# .NET sha1.ComputeHash encryption hex array equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, .net, encryption, sha1

How can I recreate this .NET hash in PHP?

```
byte[] bH = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sT);
SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
byte[] hB = sha1.ComputeHash(bH);
StringBuilder hS = new StringBuilder(hB.Length * 2);
foreach (byte b in hB) {
   hS.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
}
finalValue = hS.ToString();
```

Comment: What sort of service is it then?

Comment: It says "A site for programmers... (to) ...ask a clear practical question to actual problems". Don't see how my question doesn't fit into that.

Comment: Well I'm sorry that the format of my question offends you but I think it's a semantic argument and with all due respect I maintain that there's nothing I've read in the guidelines to which you pointed me that would suggest your way is right and mine is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
$finalValue = sha1($sT);
```